# Office Addin Dialog Api issue

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I've created an Office 365 Add-in using the Dialog API example on "[Dialog API in your Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)". When I test the add-in on multiple workstations the dialog works perfectly everywhere except on one. The problem happens when I click a button to initiate a dialog so I can authenticate to Office 365 and nothing happens on that computer.

The `dialogCallback` function is returning a failed status and a error message of `An internal error has occurred`.

All workstations are running Word version 1702 (Build 7870.2038), but that one computer the dialog isn't working on is on Windows 7 running IE 11 version 11.0.9600.16428 (Update Versions: RTM (KB2841134)).

The other workstations are on Windows 10 using IE 11 version 11.1066.14393.0 (KB4014661). The dialog isn't working on both Word online and Word 2016.

Is the Dialog API not compatible for that version of IE 11?

Chrome and Firefox are fine.

```js
$scope.startLogin = function () {
    if (hostType == "OFFICE_ONLINE") {
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/Auth.html", {
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            displayInIframe: true
        }, dialogCallback);
    } else {
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/Auth.html", {
            height: 40,
            width: 40
        }, dialogCallback);
    }
};

function dialogCallback(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
        switch (asyncResult.error.code) {
            case 12004:
                console.log("Domain is not trusted");
                break;
            case 12005:
                console.log("HTTPS is required");
                break;
            case 12007:
                console.log("A dialog is already opened.");
                break;
            default:
                console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        /*Messages are sent by developers programatically from the dialog using office.context.ui.messageParent(...)*/
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);

        /*Events are sent by the platform in response to user actions or errors. For example, the dialog is closed via the 'x' button*/
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, eventHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side Issue: You don't need to check for host_type if the only thing the code does differently for Office Online is pass "displayInIframe: true". That value is just ignored on non-Online hosts, so you can safely pass it to all hosts.

Comment: Thanks if thats the case I'll remove the check. Thanks you